# Array of Strings converted in Hash with the strings on keys (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, string, hash, key

I wonder if is it possible to convert an Array that contains strings to a Hash that have this strings by keys.

For example:
  arr = ["k1","k2","k3"]   to  hs = {:k1 => "Don't care", :k2 => "...", :k3 =>"..."}

I tried Hash["k1","k2"] but is not that I'm looking for :)

Sorry I had forgot the language, is "Ruby"

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Which language are you working in?